# How to use a pyqtsignal to transmit a window which retains its function?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, signals-slots

I use a pyqt_signal to transmit a sub window, which has a button whose function is to print. I use a thread to transmit this sub window to the main window to show, however the button loses its function. I know that I should put the statement `self.sub_window = SubWindow()` into the `__init__` function in the second class, but how can I achieve the same effect if I still put this statement here.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import currentThread

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread


class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('push me to print ***')
        self.button.move(200, 200)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_)

    def print_(self):
        print('***')


class SignalStore(QThread):
    window_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super(SignalStore, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        # if i put this statement here, how can i acquire window's print button function
        self.sub_window = SubWindow()
        self.window_signal.emit(self.sub_window)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('push me to get subwindow')
        self.button.move(200, 200)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.send_signal)

        self.med_signal = SignalStore()
        self.med_signal.window_signal.connect(self.get_sub_window)

    def send_signal(self):
        self.med_signal.start()

    def get_sub_window(self, para):
        self.sub_window = para
        self.sub_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Don't create gui objects inside threads.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create or access gui objects inside threads. [Read Qt guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).

> **GUI Thread and Worker Thread**
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main thread.

This is probably what you are looking for:

```py
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread, pyqtSlot


class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('push me to print ***')
        self.button.move(200, 200)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_)
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def print_(self):
        print('hello from subwindow')


class SignalStore(QThread):
    print_func = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(SignalStore, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1) # fake working...
        self.print_func.emit("hello from thread")


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.subwin = SubWindow()
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('push me to get subwindow')
        self.button.move(200, 200)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.send_signal)

        self.med_signal = SignalStore()
        self.med_signal.print_func.connect(self.print_from_main)
        
    def send_signal(self):
        self.subwin.show()
        self.med_signal.start()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def print_from_main(self, string: str):
        print(string)
        self.subwin.print_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my case it may take a long time to instantiate a sub window and it may make the main window freezed. So I choose to instantiate a sub window inside a thread and manage to transmit the sub window back to the main window. I do not know other solutions or choices.

Comment: @ydx As I said you can't do that, you will need to load that window in advance.
Also there is no reason why instantiating a window would take so long so You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @ניר Please don't post quotes as images, just use text and eventually format it. Besides, there are many situations for which showing the UI might take some time: it could need to connect to a network resource and wait for a response, load some amount of data from slow access resources, build complex data structures, or just be a very complex UI.

Comment: @musicamante Re: "Please don't post quotes as images" - Understood, Will fix.  
Re: "Besides, there are many situations for which showing the UI might take some time"  
I agree, What I meant was that if it does and other parts of the GUI freezes you are probably doing something wrong. l.e calling IO/CPU bound code in the GUI thread. Other than that If the GUI itself is taking long time to load you may want to load that window in advance.